# What tools can I use to automate dealing with chrome extension manifest v3 requirement for all javascript to be locally referenced?

Tags: chrome

With the new Chrome extension manifest v3 we [no longer have the ability to use externally hosted javascript files in our extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71823208/101679).

I would like to still be able to write code like the following in my popup.html file:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@github/auto-complete-element@3.5.1/dist/bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="module">
        import {
                html,
                render
            } from 'https://unpkg.com/lit-html@2.8.0/lit-html.js'
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Are there any tools that can be used to parse html and js files, find the urls of external resources in those files, download those external resources locally, and then rewrite the references in the files to point to relative paths of the locally downloaded copies?